# How to remove deepest sublayer from view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, calayer

What would be the method of removing the deepest sublayer from a view's main layer? Should be pretty simple, I'm very new to iOS.

Comment: By deepest, do you mean the one at the back? or do you mean deepest as in, view.sublayers.sublayers.... etc till you cannot go any more

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really mean the layer (not view) in the back, you can try this as well:

```
[[view.layer.sublayers objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperlayer];
```

If you want to remove the back view instead, you can use the similar:

```
[[view.subviews objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
```

Of course, if you really want to remove the *deepest* sublayer/subview, including those of child views, you'll have to do something like this:

```
CALayer *layer = view.layer;
while ([layer.sublayers count] > 0) {
    layer = [layer.sublayers objectAtIndex:0];
}
[layer removeFromSuperlayer];
```

Still, that seems like a bad idea. If you're really looking for that, I'd recommend rethinking what you're actually looking for.

Comment: Alright, this works. I think I was just confused myself the layer schema in iOS.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean the back most subview, use:

```
UIView *subViewToBeRemoved = [mainView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
[subViewToBeRemoved removeFromSuperview];
```

mainView.subviews will return an array of the view's subviews in their visible order on screen.

If by deepest you mean the front most view you could use

```
UIView *subViewToBeRemoved = [mainView.subviews lastObject];
[subViewToBeRemoved removeFromSuperview];
```